# My goal is to click on the view details button after searching for the persons name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Whenever the search button is pressed the webpage generates a new instance however my program is not reading the new instance so it is not finding the correct "//a[@herf]".

```
def ClientInformation():
    #CI = textbox.get('1.0', END)
    CI = "first name, Last Name"
    city = "City, State"
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    

    #Installs and Opens Chrome to "Truepeoplesearch.com"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                              options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/")
    #Enters data from UI to text fields and searches
    driver.find_element(by="name", value="CityStateZip").send_keys(city)
    driver.find_element(by="name", value="Name").send_keys(CI)
    if len(driver.find_elements("xpath", "//a[@herf]")) > 0:
        driver.find_elements("xpath","//a[@herf]")[0].click()
    else:
        print("you suck")
```

It always prints you suck :(

^^^^^^^ Doesn't work as well as I intended vvvvvvvvvvv new iteration

solved

```
CI = textbox.get('1.0', END)
    #Split Client Information by " : "
    CIS = re.split(r' ', str(CI))

    FN = CIS[0]
    LN = CIS[1]
    CT = CIS[2]
    ST = CIS[3]

driver.get("https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/results?name=" + FN + "%20" + LN +"&citystatezip= " + CT + " %20" + ST + "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is blocking me so I can't test your script, but I would guess that you have a typo in there, and `("xpath","//a[@herf]")` should instead read `("xpath","//a[@href]")`

Comment: as i was waiting for a response i found another way around and its much more reliable and faster however I'm newbie at code (like 1 month old xD) and trying to figure out how to take my block of text split it into a string and then mark each word in that string as a variable. I'll make a new post with that.

rip me, thank you!